# i want display chart based on selected charts using chartJS

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

[see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ulFw.png) i want to display all charts based on selected chart in dropdown
the json data is  `[ { "ChartGroupName": "Group-A", "Apple": 45, "Banana": 37, "Kiwi_fruit": 60, "Blueberry": 70, "Orange": 46, "Grape_Fruit": 33 }, { "ChartGroupName": "Group-B", "Apple": 50, "Banana": 35, "Kiwi_fruit": 70, "Blueberry": 65, "Orange": 40, "Grape_Fruit": 53 }, { "ChartGroupName": "Group-C", "Apple": 55, "Banana": 39, "Kiwi_fruit": 80, "Blueberry": 75, "Orange": 52, "Grape_Fruit": 73 } ]` can any help me

Comment: You need to show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2016 and later you can use [FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) clause. It's similar to the old `FOR XML` clause, but generates JSON string, rather then XML string.

If you want to nested, you may look for [PATH mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-nested-json-output-with-path-mode-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). It's pretty easy:

```
   SELECT TOP 5   
       BusinessEntityID As Id,  
       FirstName, LastName,  
       Title As 'Info.Title',  
       MiddleName As 'Info.MiddleName'  
   FROM Person.Person  
   FOR JSON PATH
```

yields:

```
[{
    "Id": 1,
    "FirstName": "Ken",
    "LastName": "Sanchez",
    "Info": {
        "MiddleName": "J"
    }
}, {
    "Id": 2,
    "FirstName": "Terri",
    "LastName": "Duffy",
    "Info": {
        "MiddleName": "Lee"
    }
}, {
    "Id": 3,
    "FirstName": "Roberto",
    "LastName": "Tamburello"
}, {
    "Id": 4,
    "FirstName": "Rob",
    "LastName": "Walters"
}, {
    "Id": 5,
    "FirstName": "Gail",
    "LastName": "Erickson",
    "Info": {
        "Title": "Ms.",
        "MiddleName": "A"
    }
}]
```

For older version, you will need to build the JSON strings using concatenation using for `XML PATH`.